# How to render the output of my action

Tags: grails

My controller:

```
def getMenuItemCount(String name){

   def myCount = MenuItem.countByMenuItemCategory(name)

   render myCount
}
```

What do i call in another gsp so that `myCount` appears. `createLink` doesnt seem to work

`${createLink(action:'getMenuItemCount', params: [name:ci.name])}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A model has to be returned instead of rendering it in order to access it in a gsp.

```
def getMenuItemCount(String name){

   [ myCount: MenuItem.countByMenuItemCategory(name) ]

}
```

Also, (not related to question really), try to avoid using action names as `get*` and `set*`. I have seen discrepancies with that nomenclature.

Comment: Then how do use it on other gsp? I mean how do i get its output on a separate gsp

Comment: Is `${myCount}` causing any problem? Wherever `createLink` will be used the way you have in question, the model should be accessible, isn't it?

Comment: i tried this `${createLink(action:'getMenuItemCount', params: [name:ci.name])}` it just gives me a url

Comment: You need to go through [`createLink`](http://www.grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html) docs to see how you can also provide a controller name and action name.